# Observable being fired continuously

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

There is a page in my app which retrieves the members of the app and displays them on the page. When retrieving the members, the response back from the api includes pagination information and only 5 users are displayed on the page. Here is the method in the `member.service` that retrieves the members:

```
memberCache = new Map();

getMembers(memberParams: MemberParams) {
    
        const response = this.memberCache.get(Object.values(memberParams).join('-'));
    
        if(response) {
          console.log(response); // This is being fired continuously
          return of(response);
        }
    
        let params = new HttpParams(); 
    
          params = params.append('pageNumber', memberParams.pageNumber.toString()); 
          params = params.append('pageSize', memberParams.pageSize.toString());
          params = params.append('usersLocation', memberParams.usersLocation);
        
        
        return this.paginationService.getPaginatedResult<Member[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/`, memberParams).pipe(map(response => {
          this.memberCache.set(Object.values(memberParams).join('-'), response);
          return response;
        }));
      }
```

As you can see from the above, when the paginated result is retrieved from the api, is is stored in the `memberCache` Map. This prevents the method from retrieving the data from the server if it is already stored locally.

Within the same service file, I have a `BehaviourSubject` which wraps the `MemberParams`:

```
membersObs$: BehaviorSubject<MemberParams> = new BehaviorSubject(new MemberParams());
```

I then use `switchMap` to switch the `membersObs$` BehaviorSubject to the Observable returned by the `this.getMembers` method when the BehaviorSubject is triggered:

```
members$ = this.membersObs$.pipe(switchMap(memberParams => this.getMembers(memberParams)));
```

The `membersObs$` BehaviorSubject is triggered when this method is called:

```
setMemberParams(memberParams: MemberParams) {
    this.membersObs$.next(memberParams);
  }
```

In the component file, the `members$` observable from the `members.service` is assigned to a variable, a new instance of the `MemberParams` is created and the `loadMembers()` method is called:

```
ngOnInit() {

   this.membersObs$ = this.memberService.members$;
   this.memberParams = new MemberParams();
   this.loadMembers();

}
```

Here is the `loadMembers()` method:

```
loadMembers() {
    this.memberService.setMemberParams(this.memberParams);
  }
```

Here is the relevant html code from the component file:

```
<div *ngIf="membersObs$ | async as membersObs$" class="row d-flex justify-content-center members-container">
            <div *ngFor="let member of membersObs$.result" class="col-2 members">
                <app-member-card [member]="member"></app-member-card>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" *ngIf="membersObs$ | async as membersObs$">
            <pagination
              [boundaryLinks]="true"
              [totalItems]="membersObs$.pagination.totalItems"
              [itemsPerPage]="membersObs$.pagination.itemsPerPage"
              [(ngModel)]="membersObs$.pagination.currentPage"
              (pageChanged)="pageChangedMembers($event)">
              </pagination>
            <div class="location-btns" *ngIf="(accountService.currentUser | async) as user">
                <button class="btn-primary" (click)="getLocalUsers(user.location)">{{ user.location }} users</button>
                <button class="btn-primary" (click)="getAllUsers()">All users</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The issue I am having is that when the page is changed using the `pageChangedMembers($event)` method, the  observable returned from the `getMembers()` method is being fired continuously and actually freezes the browser page because of it.

Here is the `pageChangedMembers($event)` method from within the component:

```
 pageChangedMembers(event: any) {
    this.memberParams.pageNumber = event.page;
    this.memberService.setMemberParams(this.memberParams);
  }
```

See this image of the browser console when the issue occurs:

[image]

*****EDIT****

Upon further inspection, it is actually the `pageChangedMembers($event)` method that is being called continuously.

Comment: In `*ngIf="membersObs$ | async as membersObs$"` why are you using the same name for 'as' any specific reason for that? finding it confusing for reading. This could not be the root cause for the problem you are seeing. Is the `pageChangedMembers` getting called multiple times or it is the `getMembers` getting called multiple times?

Comment: It is the actually the `pageChangedMembers($event)` that is being called multiple times. I have just checked. I will edit the OP

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was accidentally binding to the `currentPage` property of the `paginatedResponse` observable rather than binding to the `pageNumber` of the `memberParams`:

```
<pagination
   [boundaryLinks]="true"
   [totalItems]="paginatedResponse.pagination.totalItems"
   [itemsPerPage]="paginatedResponse.pagination.itemsPerPage"
   [(ngModel)]="memberParams.pageNumber"
   (pageChanged)="pageChangedMembers($event)">
</pagination>
```

This now works